# dplyr-friendly user function to use with join functions

Tags: r, function, dplyr

The work I do involves merging several databases from different sources on a key look-up variable. The variable is a string variable and often spelled many different ways depending on the source of the data (i.e., 'New York City', 'City of New York').

I've written a simple function to clean look-up variables in each dataset and am using it in this manner:

```
clean.names <- function(x){
  x %>% 
    str_remove_all('[:punct:]') %>% 
    str_to_lower() %>% 
    str_squish() %>% 
    str_trim()
}

#df_1 and df_2 are dataframes, with variables key that I use to merge. 
df_1 %>% 
  mutate(clean_name = clean.names(key1)) %>% 
  left_join(df_2 %>% 
              mutate(clean_name = clean.names(key2)), 
            by = 'clean_name')
```

This function works quite well in doing what it's intended for. However, the code is a bit verbose. My question is: How can I create a function that works with dplyr (i.e., no quotes, etc.) that produces the same effect as what's above? I'd like it to be in true dplyr form and work as a wrapper in the join functions. I have tried my hand at this with no success, see here:

```
clean.names <- function(x =df, y = merge.vary){ # function adds
  x$merge.vary <- y %>%                         # a new variable
    str_remove_all('[:punct:]') %>%             # to existing dataframe
    str_to_lower() %>% 
    str_squish() %>% 
    str_trim()
}


clean.names(df_1, key1) %>%         # then use the function as a wrapper
  left_join(clean.names(df_2, key2))# for the dplyr join functions
```

Is there a way to do this? What I'd like to have is a dplyr-esque acting function that looks like: function(dataframe, variable). Thanks.

Comment: Maybe worth exploring: the [`fuzzyjoin` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, I looked into that and couldn't quite figure out exactly how to get things to join up. I'll have another look.

Comment: *"How can I create a function that works with dplyr"* - any function that takes a data frame as it's first argument and returns a data frame works pretty well with `dplyr`. *"(i.e., no quotes, etc.)"* That's harder. The [Programming with dplyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rlang::ensym()` to capture the variable name and pass it directly to `mutate_at`:

```
library(tidyverse)
clean.names2 <- function( .df, .var ) {
  f <- compose( partial(str_remove_all, pattern='[:punct:]'), 
                 str_to_lower, str_squish, str_trim )
  .df %>% mutate_at( vars(!!ensym(.var)), f )
}
```

The function works with variable names provided with and without quotes:

```
X <- tibble( Cities = c("  New York City, NY", "Denver, CO;;") )
clean.names2( X, Cities )
# # A tibble: 2 x 1
#   Cities          
#   <chr>           
# 1 new york city ny
# 2 denver co       

clean.names2( X, "Cities" )  ## equivalent
```

**Brief explanation:**

The first line creates a composite function by stringing together `str_remove_all`, `str_to_lower`, `str_squish`, `str_trim` and using `partial()` to assign a prespecified value to the `pattern` parameter of `str_remove_all`. The resulting function `f` is identical to your original `clean.names`. (I just tried to make `clean.names2` self-contained.)

The second line applies the new composite function `f` (or equivalently, your original `clean.names`) to a single column in `.df` using `mutate_at`. The column is specified using two tidyverse mechanisms. The first is `vars()`, which allows users to specify column names with and without quotes. For example, the following two lines are equivalent:

```
mydf %>% mutate_at( vars("mycolumn"), myfunction )  # vars can be dropped here
mydf %>% mutate_at( vars(mycolumn), myfunction )
```

The second mechanism belongs to the class of functions that deal with [quasiquoatation](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html), allowing programmers to work directly with unevaluated expressions, including those provided by the function users. In particular, we use `ensym` to capture a symbol provided to the function by the calling environment and pass that symbol to `vars`. The `!!` is important, because it tells `vars` to go ahead and evaluate the expression `ensym(.var)` and use the result as the column name. Without `!!`, `vars` would be trying to find a column with the name "ensym(.var)" instead.

Comment: Thanks, this works well! Do you mind explaining what's happening here?

Comment: I find this link helpful for understanding the bang-bang `!!` notation: http://jonthegeek.com/2018/06/04/writing-custom-tidyverse-functions/